# Did they use the clojurescript transpiler to transpile the transpiler?

Tags: clojurescript, transpiler

I don't know how the "self hosted" clojurescript implementations like [this](https://github.com/planck-repl/planck) and [this](https://github.com/anmonteiro/lumo) are implemented.

However, given that the clojurescript compiler is written in clojure and it compiles clojure to javascript, I can reason that the clojurescript transpiler could theoretically transpile it's own source code to javascript, producing a clojurescript transpiler on the browser/node platform. I was just curious, is that feasible and actually how it's done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your description sounds fairly accurate.

Here is a post that provides some explanation:

https://blog.fikesfarm.com/posts/2015-07-17-what-is-bootstrapped-clojurescript.html

and a talk that covers some of the same subject, especially near the beginning:

https://youtu.be/HnQ89r_dKEM

Comment: Is this still the best place to start in 2021 or have their been other developments? It still feels pretty difficult to get started on this path.